# How to call Telerik RadGrid Method protected void RadGrid1_CustomAggregate(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridCustomAggregateEventArgs e)

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I have a column of radiobuttonlist in radgrid and I want to call Telerik RadGrid Method

```
protected void RadGrid1_CustomAggregate(object sender, GridCustomAggregateEventArgs e)
```

in another event as selection changes Aggregate Recalculate values

```
protected void radiobuttonList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  RadGrid1_CustomAggregate(???????)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is really possible, since you need to know the data to pass to the event. IF you do, you can use the class's constructor to pass arguments, e.g.:

```
GridCustomAggregateEventArgs args = new GridCustomAggregateEventArgs(RadGrid1.Items[0], RadGrid1.Columns[0], "");
RadGrid1_CustomAggregate(RadGrid1, args);
```

but I do not know what logic you should employ to get the data. Download the code and see how it is called internally perhaps, so you can emulate it?

Or try calling the Rebind() method of the grid in case this lets it pick up the changes and execute queries again.